# Runtime error: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore

Tags: ios, cocoapods, amazon-mobile-analytics

I'm using AWS Mobile Analytics for iOS (2.2.3). After running pod update, I'm getting the following error when trying to run `MyApp` on a physical device:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore
>        Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4582B679-A162-47CE-80ED-58C8B9BB231B/MyApp.app/MyApp
>        Reason: Incompatible library version: MyApp requires version 2.0.0 or later, but AWSCore provides version 1.0.0

My cocoapods pod file entry for the AWS Mobile Analytics library is:

```
pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics'
```

I've tried decrementing the `AWSMobileAnalytics` version (`pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics', '2.2.2'`), but I still get the same error. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cleared the DerivedData folder (`/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`), then rebuilt the app, and it worked.

**Edit**

I got this error again when attempting to add a new primary target to my project. I would get the same error as above when defining the Podfile as such:

```
target 'MainTarget' do
    pod 'MyCocoapod'
    target 'SecondMainTarget' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

To fix this, I had to define the Podfile like this:

```
def my_pods
    pod 'MyCocoapod'
end

target 'MainTarget' do
    my_pods
end

target 'SecondMainTarget' do
    my_pods
end
```

Comment: I need to get "clear Derived Data" tattooed on my arm.

Comment: I have two schemas. Fixing the Podfile worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by following the Framework install process detailed on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup-aws-sdk-for-ios.html

It was the embedded binaries that I'd forgotten to do.

Comment: It's a late answer, to a question that is already accepted. In this case add a little more supportive evidence or commentary as to why your solution might be superior to the others. You have pointed out a good common scenario where your answer definitely applies, so flesh it out with specific instructions on how to verify if the binaries have been included or not.

Comment: The best fix is as pointed by Damibu, you have to add the Embedded Binaries to the General Tab which can be seen by right clicking the project -> General Tab
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfWCY.png)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by unchecking 'Run script only when installing' which can be found under [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks in the Build Phases section of your project Targets[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `Podfile.lock` file and then do `pod install`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. It required me to delete the derived data folder, as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set path as below
[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

I had to change

```
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

to

```
use_frameworks!
```